# In Ublock Origin how do I modify the style of div depending on if it has a child's child?

Tags: adblock

In UBlcok Origin I'm trying to hide the search/header bar at the top of Youtube when on a video page, but not when on the home page.  It's been far trickier then I imagined because youtube not only reuses ids on the same page, but also reuses the same ids and classes on the home page as the video pages - so I thought I would try and use a [procedural cosmetic filter](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Procedural-cosmetic-filters).

So far I have:

```
! stop search bar from floating when scrolling
youtube.com###masthead-container.ytd-app:style(position: static !important)
! remove resulting whitespace (search bar still remains for some reason)
youtube.com###masthead-container:style(height: 0 !important)
! move video up to cover search bar but only if #content's ytd-page-manager element contains a ytd-watch-flexy element
youtube.com###content.style-scope.ytd-app:has(ytd-page-manager:has(ytd-watch-flexy)):style(position: relative; top: -56px !important)
```

but the last line doesn't work.  So I changed it to call the custom youtube elements by id and class:

```
youtube.com###content.style-scope.ytd-app:has(#page-manager:has(.hide-skeleton)):style(position: relative; top: -56px !important)
```

and it will successfully select the correct `#content` element if I remove the `:style(...)` conditional - but, as shown, it doesn't appear to apply hide or apply the style if I chain a `:style()` to the `:has()` conditional.

Can you chain `:has()` and `:style()`?

Comment: as of 2016 it was being discussed about adding it https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/issues/781#issuecomment-234574575

Comment: a WORKAROUND that puts the video at the top of the page in theater mode, and has the search bar on the homepage, but doesn't prevent it from being docked while scrolling:
`youtube.com###masthead-container:style(position: relative; height: 0; z-index: 0 !important)`
`youtube.com###content.style-scope.ytd-app:style(position: relative; top: -56px; !important)`

Answer (score 1):

The feature of chaining conditionals to `:style()` has not been added as of the end of 2019

https://github.com/uBlockOrigin/uBlock-issues/issues/382